# Track republic wireless texts over wifi

Tags: motorola-defy

My son has a republic phone and I'm trying to find a way to monitor his texts without modifying anything on his phone because he's fairly tech savvy so he'd be able to remove it. I was thinking about a way to track the texts when they go over wifi. is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, so I won't post it as an answer. But have you seen [Mobile Spy](http://www.wikihow.com/Spy-on-Android-Phones-Using-Mobile-Spy) or [Stealth Genie](http://www.stealthgenie.com/features/sms.html)?

Comment: Are you tech savvy? You could try Wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

SMS messages (aka "text messages") don't go over Wi-Fi, so it's not possible to track them that way. If you don't think you can install anything on the phone, the only way is through the carrier, and since intercepting other people's communications is against the law in most places, they're not likely to help you do that.

Comment: Please read the question carefully It says republic wireless. Their primary feature is to be able to text and call over wifi

Comment: I read the question carefully and it didn't say anything about this being a VOIP carrier. You might like to include that information so nobody else will waste their time trying to help, when only someone local to you will be able to give a useful answer. Regardless, if any of their data pass unencrypted over Wi-Fi, you should switch carrier.

Comment: [Republic Wireless](https://republicwireless.com/)